# Cordova: InAppBrowser working on android emulator but not on android device

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I'm trying to get InAppBrowser to launch a browser window from my app.  When I try using my code on an Android emulator running from Visual Studio the browser launches as expected, but when I install an apk (built through Adobe PhoneGap build) to my Android device, I push the button and nothing occurs.  I've verified that the event is indeed executing through an alert() on the device, but the browser isn't opening up.  Any ideas?

HTML:

```
    <div class="app">
        <div>
            <input type="button" id="launch" value="Launch browser to www.google.com!"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    document.addEventListener( 'deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind( this ), false );

    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Handle the Cordova pause and resume events
        document.addEventListener( 'pause', onPause.bind( this ), false );
        document.addEventListener('resume', onResume.bind(this), false);
        document.querySelector('input#launch').addEventListener('click', launchGoogle);
    };

    function onPause() {
        // TODO: This application has been suspended. Save application state here.
    };

    function onResume() {
        // TODO: This application has been reactivated. Restore application state here.
    };
})();

function launchGoogle() {
    alert("launchGoogle()");
    cordova.InAppBrowser.open("http://www.google.com", "_blank", "location=yes");
}
```

I tried wrapping my call using a try statement and get the error "*Cannot call method 'open' of undefined*".  I assume this means the InAppBrowser plugin isn't getting installed.

Comment: Do you have whitelist setup?

Comment: @J.Polfer I feel that the launchGoogle function that has plugin invocation code should be placed inside onDeviceReady function.. You can check out a simple working sample app here - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_InAppBrowser Also ensure to have proper permissions set in config.xml

Comment: @Ghandi - I tried wrapping my call using a try statement and get the error "Cannot call method 'open' of undefined".  I assume this means the InAppBrowser plugin isn't getting installed.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was the plugin wasn't being loaded.  Reason:  the plugins weren't being downloaded.

Turns out the plugins weren't being downloaded by PhoneGap Build.  Reason:  PhoneGap build needs your config.xml in the www/ directory, not in the root project directory as Visual Studio had it originally.

Copying the config.xml file to the www/ directory fixed the problem.